# I am making a website for playing a card game with firebase and I am using realtime database, but when someone draws an card it makes a endless loop

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, playing-cards

When someone draws a card (the shift function) like cardDeck.shift(); it takes a card out of the player's card deck then takes one out of the realtime databases informing the user playing against him to take a card out of there's. I feel this is the best way to do it instead of having to load in the entire deck every time someone pulls a card. But as you can easily see this creates an endless loop. The database needs to call the same function or the player's will not update when the opponent draws a card. Do you have any suggestions on ways around this? Thanks in advance.

I understand why it is happening that it keeps calling itself. I would like to know a different method. I have yet to be able to think of one.

```
class Deck{
    shift(){
        let temp = this.cards.shift();
        this.syncShift();
        return temp;
    }

    syncShift(){
        dbDeck.child('cards').child(String(mainDeck.cards.length-1)).remove();
    }
    }

dbDeck.child('cards').on('child_removed', function (snap) {
    console.log(snap.val());
    mainDeck.shift();
})
cardDeck.shift();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is cycle going on as far as i see , shift -> syncShift -> shift ,
shift() call syncShift() and it removes it a card, which triggers "child_removed" and again it calls shift().

Comment: Do players have separate db? How are they saved? It would be good if you can show us your table schema.

Comment: There’s not much to show. It’s just a variable called p1Hand, p2Hand, deck, and center hand. Otherwise that’s it at this point I just started working on it about a week ago. No the players don’t have separate dbs. Though that might be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling shift which takes a card out of my hand and then takes a card out of the database. Take it straight out of the database which in turn takes it out of my hand. Flip the order and it’ll work

Answer (score 0):

**"DIVIDE AND CONQUER."** The action "picking a card" can be separated into 3 sub actions:

1. Removing card from UI
2. Removing card locally (from class)
3. Removing card from db

Knowing this, we can then create functions for each sub-action:

1. `removeCardFromUI`
2. `removeCardFromMemory`
3. `removeCardFromDb`

We will still call the function for the main action `shift` and `syncShift` for the other one.

Let's assume the deck is saved in the db and both players share the same deck.

```
class Deck {
  removeCardFromUI() {
    var deck; //the UI deck
    deck.child('cards').child(String(mainDeck.cards.length - 1)).remove();
  }
  //remove card from memory
  removeCardFromMemory() {
    let temp = this.cards.shift();
    return temp;
  }
  //your function that syncs the db
  removeCardFromDb(card) {
    //however you do it here
  }
  shift() {
    this.removeCardFromUI();
    let temp = this.removeCardFromMemory();
    this.removeCardFromDb(temp);
    return temp
  }
  syncShift() {
    this.removeCardFromUI();
    this.removeCardFromMemory();
  }
}
cardDeck.shift();
```

Now, let's say `P1` picked a card. We will then call `shift()` for `P1` which as you can see will call `removeCardFromUI`, `removeCardFromMemory` and `removeCardFromDb`. After so, once the db is updated, we will call `syncShift` for `P2`. This will in turn just call `removeCardFromUI` and `removeCardFromMemory`. No more `removeCardFromDb` as that will trigger an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Having your own local copy of the deck at all is probably a bad idea. It's critically important in any application that there be only one authoritative source of each piece of information and unnecessary caching risks confusion. And if the database must be updated before the next operation can start anyway, then the cache isn't buying you much. Firebase "Realtime Database" is called that for a reason--it is specifically designed for keeping multiple clients in sync in realtime. Use its functions as they are intended, and trust that Google is more likely to get it right than you are.